# JavaScript comparing the value within divs to write within a div

Tags: javascript

Within my webpage I want to determine whether my item is on sale. I have a spreadsheet of values that are on sale, the initial price and a value which shows whether the item is on sale.

I have put this on my webpage within divs as below for example:

```
<div class="items">
<div class="onSale" id="onSale">79.99</div>
<div class="initialCost" id="initialCost">30.00</div>
<div class="actualSellingValue" id="actualSellingValue"></div>
</div>
```

I will have a huge amount of products within the items and need to write JavaScript to write within the `actualSellingValue` the actual value. So the script needs to look at if the first `onSale` div is null then just write the value within `initialCost` into the `actualSellingValue`. The next condition needs to check if there is a onSale value write that value within the div.

I am new to JavaScript and have no idea how to do this.

Comment: at first: has every items-div the three child divs with the same ids? ids should be unique or is this just a simplification here?

Comment: All items the child divs will have the same ids, the value needs to be written within the actualSellingValue div. Thanks

Comment: then remove the ids, you mustn´t have two or more domElements with the same id, that dorrupts the principle of an id, an identifier.

Comment: But all this needs is to check the onSale value if null then write the value in initialCost within the actualSellingValue div. If it is not null write the value within the onSale value in actualSellingValue. I just dont know how to go about it. Thanks

Comment: actually all IDs will be different for different products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var onSale = document.getElementById("onSale").innerHTML;
var initialCost = document.getElementById("initialCost").innerHTML;
var actualSellingValue = document.getElementById("actualSellingValue");

if (onSale === "") {
   actualSellingValue.innerHTML = initialCost;
} else {
  actualSellingValue.innerHTML = onSale;   
}
```

However if you have more than one `div` with ID items, `onSale`, `initialCost`, `actualSellingValue` etc then this will only work for the first set (As it should as HTML identifiers should be unique)

http://jsfiddle.net/eWe5J/4/

Comment: Thanks this works, would a good way to write this if I want it for all the ids of the prodcuts be write it for each product within items?

Comment: arggh, why dont you listen, remove the ids!